# Error al parsear json en android : t usuario of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray

Tags: android, json

tengo un String que necesito parsear y me da el siguiente error:

> Value {"nombre":"prueba","codigo":"1","foto":"prueba"} at usuario of
>   type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray

el formato de mi json es el siguiente:

```
{"Error":false,"usuario":{"nombre":"prueba","codigo":"1","foto":"prueba"}}
```

y este es el codigo que tengo:

```
public void parseJson(String respuesta){
        String nombre="d";
        int codigo=0;
        String foto="d";
        try {
            JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(respuesta);
            Boolean error = jObject.getBoolean("Error");
            if (error){
                String error_msg= jObject.getString("Error_msg");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error: "+error_msg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else {

                JSONArray jArray = jObject.getJSONArray("usuario");

                JSONObject oneObject = jArray.getJSONObject(0);
                nombre = oneObject.getString("nombre");
                foto = oneObject.getString("foto");
                codigo = oneObject.getInt("codigo");

                String mensaje = "tu nombre es: " + nombre + ", tu codigo es: " + codigo + " y tu perfil es: " + foto;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), mensaje, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error al parsear datos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("error parseando",e.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

espero puedan ayudarme

Comment: En que linea te marca el error?

Comment: nombre = oneObject.getString("nombre");
                foto = oneObject.getString("foto");
                codigo = oneObject.getInt("codigo"); , estas son las lineas que me dan error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revisa la estructura de tu json:

```
{"Error":false,"usuario":{"nombre":"prueba","codigo":"1","foto":"prueba"}}
```

en realidad "usuario" es un objeto (recuerda Objeto: "{", array "[" ), y no un array, por lo tanto esta linea tendrá el problema:

```
 JSONArray jArray = jObject.getJSONArray("usuario");
```

debes cambiar a :

```
 JSONObject jObject2 = jObject.getJSONObject("usuario");
```

---

Código:

```
   public void parseJson(String respuesta){
        String nombre="d";
        int codigo=0;
        String foto="d";
        try {
            JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(respuesta);
            Boolean error = jObject.getBoolean("Error");
            if (error){
                String error_msg= jObject.getString("Error_msg");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error: "+error_msg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else {

                //*No es Array es Objeto.
                //JSONArray jArray = jObject.getJSONArray("usuario");
                JSONObject jObject2 = jObject.getJSONObject("usuario");

                //*Esta linea no necesaria puesto que ya tienes el objeto.
                //JSONObject oneObject = jArray.getJSONObject(0);
                nombre = jObject2.getString("nombre");
                foto = jObject2.getString("foto");
                codigo = jObject2.getInt("codigo");

                String mensaje = "tu nombre es: " + nombre + ", tu codigo es: " + codigo + " y tu perfil es: " + foto;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), mensaje, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error al parsear datos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("error parseando",e.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

Comment: gracias, era eso :)

Comment: excelente @zhet! saludos!

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que `usuario` es un **objeto** `json`, no un **array**. Si te fijas el formato de `usuario` es el siguiente:

```
"usuario":{"nombre":"prueba","codigo":"1","foto":"prueba"}
```

El formato de un **array** json es el siguiente:

```
"frutas":["guineo", "manzana", "pera"]
```

Si te fijas los valores de un array están encerrados en llaves `[]` y separados por comas, con lo que puedes diferenciar fácilmente que es un objeto y que es un array json.

La forma correcta de obtener los valores del objeto `usuario` de acuerdo a tu json, es la siguiente:

```
...

JSONObject usuario = jObject.getJSONObject("usuario");
nombre = usuario.getString("nombre");
foto = usuario.getString("foto");
codigo = usuario.getInt("codigo");

...
```